# How to assign click event listener to drawn path in Flex 4

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, path, flex4, flex4.5

I have a spark path in mxml:

```
<s:Group id="group" click="clickHandler(event)" >
                <s:Path id="na259" x="385.301" y="140.422" winding="nonZero"   data="M2.01562 0.141602 2.32812 0.110352 2.78125 0.0322266 3.15625 0.0322266 3.59375 0 4.04688 0 4.5625 0.0322266 5.04688 0 5.59375 0 5.95312 0.0166016 6.39062 0.0166016 6.875 0.0478516 7.29688 0.0712891 7.76807 0.0712891 8.29688 0.0947266 8.78125 0.141602
                        9.28125 0.141602 9.6875 0.188477 10.0469 0.219727 10.5625 0.282227 11 0.313477 11.4062 0.360352C11.4062 0.360352 11.7969 0.422852 11.8438 0.438477 11.8906 0.454102 12.3281 0.547852 12.3281 0.547852L12.8281 0.641602 13.3125 0.782227 13.6562 0.860352
                        14.0312 0.985352 14.3906 1.1416 14.7031 1.28223 15.0781 1.43848 15.3594 1.68848 15.6719 1.98535 15.9062 2.29785 16.1875 2.79785 16.25 3.46973 16.1875 4.09473 16.125 4.6416 15.9375 5.17285 15.6875 5.79785 15.3906 6.25098 15.0469 6.73535 14.5938
                        7.15723 14.125 7.42285 13.6719 7.5791 13.208 7.5791 12.5938 7.3291 11.9844 6.90723 11.4062 6.53223 11.0625 6.29785 10.7188 6.03223 10.3438 5.93848 9.96875 6.11035 9.70312 6.37598 9.57812 6.81348 8.3125 7.04785 7.79688 6.92285 7.45312 6.7666 6.98438
                        6.67285 6.23438 6.61035 5.84375 6.6416 5.70312 6.6416 5.53125 6.67285 5.45312 6.8291 5.07812 6.65723 4.6875 6.54785 4.26562 6.48535 3.79688 6.53223 3.3125 6.65723 2.89062 6.98535 2.57812 7.23535 2.22607 7.5791 1.9375 7.8291 1.73438 8.12598 1.39062
                        8.2666 1.03125 8.12598 0.65625 7.8291 0.59375 7.5166 0.4375 7.1416 0.328125 6.68848 0.296875 6.15723 0.234375 5.7041 0.234375 5.23535 0.3125 4.65723 0.234375 4.2627 0.15625 3.84473 0.046875 3.15723 0 2.61035 0.03125 2.04785 0.078125 1.67285 0.21875
                        1.37598 0.46875 1.12598 0.734375 0.766602 1.01562 0.469727 1.39062 0.266602 2.01562 0.141602Z">
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:SolidColorStroke weight="0.25" caps="none" joints="miter" miterLimit="10"/>
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Path>
            </s:Group>
```

So, my problem is, I need to make precisely this path clickable... and not the group around it... 
the group is a box so it is not precise enough.

this tag:

```
<s:Path>
```

does bot accept an attribute 'click', so I can't create a click event listener for this tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap your Path into a group and set mouseEnabledWhereTransparent property of the Group to false.

Answer (score 0):

It will help sometime by using `Rect` component like

```
<!-- hit area -->
<s:Rect left="0" right="0" top="0" bottom="0">
    <s:fill>
        <s:SolidColor color="#000000" alpha="0"/>
    </s:fill>
</s:Rect>


<s:Group id="group" click="clickHandler(event)" >
                <s:Path id="na259" x="385.301" y="140.422" winding="nonZero"   data="M2.01562 0.141602 2.32812 0.110352 2.78125 0.0322266 3.15625 0.0322266 3.59375 0 4.04688 0 4.5625 0.0322266 5.04688 0 5.59375 0 5.95312 0.0166016 6.39062 0.0166016 6.875 0.0478516 7.29688 0.0712891 7.76807 0.0712891 8.29688 0.0947266 8.78125 0.141602
                        9.28125 0.141602 9.6875 0.188477 10.0469 0.219727 10.5625 0.282227 11 0.313477 11.4062 0.360352C11.4062 0.360352 11.7969 0.422852 11.8438 0.438477 11.8906 0.454102 12.3281 0.547852 12.3281 0.547852L12.8281 0.641602 13.3125 0.782227 13.6562 0.860352
                        14.0312 0.985352 14.3906 1.1416 14.7031 1.28223 15.0781 1.43848 15.3594 1.68848 15.6719 1.98535 15.9062 2.29785 16.1875 2.79785 16.25 3.46973 16.1875 4.09473 16.125 4.6416 15.9375 5.17285 15.6875 5.79785 15.3906 6.25098 15.0469 6.73535 14.5938
                        7.15723 14.125 7.42285 13.6719 7.5791 13.208 7.5791 12.5938 7.3291 11.9844 6.90723 11.4062 6.53223 11.0625 6.29785 10.7188 6.03223 10.3438 5.93848 9.96875 6.11035 9.70312 6.37598 9.57812 6.81348 8.3125 7.04785 7.79688 6.92285 7.45312 6.7666 6.98438
                        6.67285 6.23438 6.61035 5.84375 6.6416 5.70312 6.6416 5.53125 6.67285 5.45312 6.8291 5.07812 6.65723 4.6875 6.54785 4.26562 6.48535 3.79688 6.53223 3.3125 6.65723 2.89062 6.98535 2.57812 7.23535 2.22607 7.5791 1.9375 7.8291 1.73438 8.12598 1.39062
                        8.2666 1.03125 8.12598 0.65625 7.8291 0.59375 7.5166 0.4375 7.1416 0.328125 6.68848 0.296875 6.15723 0.234375 5.7041 0.234375 5.23535 0.3125 4.65723 0.234375 4.2627 0.15625 3.84473 0.046875 3.15723 0 2.61035 0.03125 2.04785 0.078125 1.67285 0.21875
                        1.37598 0.46875 1.12598 0.734375 0.766602 1.01562 0.469727 1.39062 0.266602 2.01562 0.141602Z">
                    <s:stroke>
                        <s:SolidColorStroke weight="0.25" caps="none" joints="miter" miterLimit="10"/>
                    </s:stroke>
                </s:Path>
            </s:Group>
```